# what is the best way to expose asynchronous data globally in nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

To solve this problem, I created a plugin that injects a property with values from my database, this is for convenience since this property stores a color that I need to use in my templates, doing it this way I have the possibility of directly accessing " $primary" and "$color" in template. However I get this warning for using "useFetch" in a plugin: "[Vue warn]: onServerPrefetch is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup(). If you are using async setup(), make sure to register lifecycle hooks before the first await statement." When using "$fetch" the warning disappears but I need those colors to send the client the page armed with the colors. Is this approach correct or is there a better way to solve this?

*plugins/colors.js*

```
import { getTextColor, hexToRgba } from "~~/utils/ColorsTools";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
  const $route = useRoute();

  const { data } = await useFetch(
    `/api/get-from-firestore?collection=shops&where=name||==||${$route.params.name}`
  );

  const { colors } = data.value[0];

  return {
    provide: {
      primary: colors.primary,
      color: getTextColor(hexToRgba(colors.primary)),
    },
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Nuxt 3, the `useFetch` composable is a wrapper around the `asyncData` and `fetch` hooks. These are meant to be called in components, not plugins.

So it is not allowed to use `useFetch` in a plugin context. Instead, you should use `$fetch`, from the `ohmyfetch` library (included in Nuxt 3), to make http requests:

```
import { $fetch } from 'ohmyfetch'
import { getTextColor, hexToRgba } from "~~/utils/ColorsTools";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
  const $route = useRoute();

  const { data } = await $fetch(
    `/api/get-from-firestore?collection=shops&where=name||==||${$route.params.name}`
  );

  const { colors } = data.value[0];

  return {
    provide: {
      primary: colors.primary,
      color: getTextColor(hexToRgba(colors.primary)),
    },
  };
});
```

Comment: If I do that I see that the request is also made on the client. I'm starting with SSR and I don't understand it very well, but I am clear seeing in the development tools that if I use useFetch (or useAsyncData) the request is only made on the server but I have access to the response on both the server and the client , without the need to make the request on the client, which I can't do with $fetch.

Comment: As I said, you can use these hooks in a plugin, so either you use them in a component, or you can also make your plugin server side only by naming the file `myplugin.server.js`.